# Why $sort on indexed fields with $group stage does not exceed RAM limit, but $sort alone does?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a collection with about 50,000 items with created indexes on e.g. `name`, and `_id`

If I use `db.items.find().sort({ name: 1, _id: 1 })`

or:

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {}  
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            name 1,
            _id: 1
        }
    }
])
```

then it exceed the RAM limit: `Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.` and I have to pass `{ allowDiskUse: true }` to aggregate if I want this to work.

However when I use `$group` stage in the aggregation pipeline it does not exceed RAM limit and it works:

```
db.items.aggregate.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {}  
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            name 1,
            _id: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: 1,
            x: {
                $push: {
                    _id: '$_id'
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Why is this happening with `$sort` alone, but not with `$sort` + `$group`?

Comment: do you have two independent indexes on name and id or a single compound index on the combination of name and id (in that order)?

Comment: I had single indexes on name and id, I didn't know about compound indexes. Now I can make a query without exceeding RAM limit. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory it's connected to [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#std-label-group-pipeline-optimization) feature.

> If a pipeline sorts and groups by the same field and the $group stage only uses the $first accumulator operator, consider adding an index on the grouped field which matches the sort order. In some cases, the $group stage can use the index to quickly find the first document of each group.

While the pipeline optimizations and the way things "actually" run is a black box this is the only thing I can think of ( that is mentioned in the docs at least ).

I'm assuming this "optimization" kicks in, making the `$group` stage utilize the index. meaning the pipeline might be holding "less" memory as it's using the index to scan this. Eventually you're not returning the `name` making the total result smaller.

Again this is pure speculation, but it's the best I got.